# Good sample/simple WPF project to get started

Tags: wpf

I am looking for a good sample/simple WPF project to get started. Any good tutorials out there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170374/good-sample-simple-wpf-project-to-get-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com) has a great blog for WPF starters.. Also, his MVVM [sample project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM) shows off some core concepts pretty well and is easy to follow.

Comment: I second the motion to start off with Josh Smith in general and the msdn project of his in specific. You will not master wpf from doing so but you will have a better idea of what the big picture is if you work though it.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at the sample applications of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at here 

`http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2007/06/13/wpf-hands-on-lab-build-an-outlook-2007-ui-clone.aspx` 
 

It is a hands-on lab that demonstrates the steps to create a user interface for business applications using WPF and Expression Blend.

Have a nice day.